# How to convert SQL to a JPQL query?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpql

I've got this SQL query which is returning count

First class:

```
public class Niveau2  implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id2emeniveau;
    private int ok;
    private int next;
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idzebra")
    private Zebra zebra;
```

Second class:

```
public class Zebra implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer idzebra;
    private String type;
    private int resolution;
    private int reseau;
    private String adresseip;
    private String snum;
    private Date dateaqui;
    private Integer affectter;
    private int etat;
    private String poste, ligne, zone, pole;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "zebra")
    private List<Niveau2> niveau2;
```

SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(ok) FROM mydb.2emeniveau 
INNER JOIN mydb.zebra ON zebra.idzebra=2emeniveau.idzebra 
WHERE 2emeniveau.ok='0' AND zebra.pole='ADT'"
```

I want to convert it to jpql

Comment: Why don't you want to keep it a SQL query? You're not fetching any entities so you're not really gaining much from JPQL. As your query might evolve, using SQL might prove to be more useful than using JPQL...

Comment: How to write jpa method for this query? SELECT * FROM do_not_track WHERE (user_id=7 ) AND ('2022-06-25' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) OR ('2022-06-30' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(nv2) FROM Niveau2 nv2 
JOIN nv2.zebras zebras 
WHERE nv2.ok = '0' AND zebras.pole = 'ADT'
```